# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: food (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM food order by id asc 2

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

am getting this error in the Logcat when I compiled the program.

according to the Logcat, these are the two places that causing the error

1

```
db=openOrCreateDatabase("Restaurants_DB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
locations = loadLocationData();
addListenerOnButton();
initializeUI();
```

2

```
HashMap<String, Location> locations = new HashMap<String, Location>();
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM foods order by id asc", null);`
```

Here are the 2 java classes that I have created:-

This is MenuFoodActivity.java class

```
public class MenuFoodActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    pizza mApp;
    private HashMap<String, Location> locations;
    ListView listView ;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_foods);

        db=openOrCreateDatabase("Restaurants_DB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        locations = loadLocationData();
        addListenerOnButton();
        initializeUI();
    }
    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Foods);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvFoods);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        String pen = o.toString();

                        mApp=((pizza) getApplicationContext());
                        mApp.setGlobalVarValue(pen);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have chosen the" + " " +  pen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //showMessage("Text","text");
                    }
                }
        );

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddFoodActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }


    private String[] getMenuFoods() {
        String[] menuFoods = new String[locations.size()];
        menuFoods = locations.keySet().toArray(menuFoods);
        return menuFoods;
    }
    private void initializeUI() {
        String[] menuFoods = getMenuFoods();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menuFoods);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id){

    }
    private void displaySelectedMenuFoods(String menuFoods){

    }
    private HashMap<String, Location> loadLocationData() {
        HashMap<String, Location> locations = new HashMap<String, Location>();
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM foods order by id asc", null);
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            locations.put("- " + c.getString(1).toString() + " : $" + c.getString(2).toString() + "", new Location(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)), c.getString(1).toString(), Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2))));
        }
        return locations;
    }

}
```

The AddDrinkActivity.java class

```
public class AddDrinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText ed_id,ed_name,ed_price;
    Button btnAdd,btnDelete,btnUpdate,btnViewAll;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_drink);

        ed_id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_Id);
        ed_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_Name);
        ed_price=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_Price);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("Restaurants_DB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food(id int, name text, price int);");
        addListenerOnButton();
    }


    public void showMessage(String title, String message){
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();

    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Delete);
        btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Update);
        btnViewAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_View);


        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO food VALUES('"+ed_id.getText()+"','"+ed_name.getText()+"','"+ed_price.getText()+"');");
                showMessage("Success", "Drink added");
            }

        });


        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db.execSQL("UPDATE food SET name='"+ed_name.getText()+"', price='"+ed_price.getText()+"' WHERE id='"+ ed_id.getText()+"'");
                showMessage("Success","Drink Modified");
            }
        });



        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM drinks WHERE id='"+ed_id.getText()+"'");
                showMessage("Success", "Drink Deleted");
            }

        });


        btnViewAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM food", null);
                if(cursor.getCount()==0){
                    showMessage("Error","No records founds");
                    return;
                }
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                    buffer.append("Id: "+cursor.getString(0)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Name: "+cursor.getString(1)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Price: "+cursor.getString(2)+"\n\n");
                }
                showMessage("Drink Details",buffer.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
04-26 14:48:55.336 21103-21103/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto E/DATABASE OPERATIONS: Database created /Opened...
04-26 14:48:55.593 21103-21103/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto E/DATABASE OPERATIONS: Database created /Opened...
04-26 14:48:55.753 21103-21121/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
04-26 14:48:58.743 21103-21103/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: food
04-26 14:48:58.746 21103-21103/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto, PID: 21103
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto.MenuDrinksActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: food (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM food order by id asc
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: food (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM food order by id asc
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:901)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:512)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1401)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1340)
        at com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto.MenuDrinksActivity.loadLocationData(MenuDrinksActivity.java:79)
        at com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto.MenuDrinksActivity.onCreate(MenuDrinksActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7117)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7108)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
```

now error was created in the total activity java class

here is the logcat

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto/com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto.TotalActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
 Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2036)
    at com.example.prudentmubasha.ainnaresto.TotalActivity.onCreate(TotalActivity.java:33)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7117)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7108)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

04-28 21:19:42.719 1676-2777/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da

here is the place error occured

```
enter c while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), st.nextElement().toString().substring(0,1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        test = st.nextElement().toString().substring(3,1);
        if(count>0)
            total+= Float.parseFloat(test);
        count++;
    }
```

here is the total activity java class file

```
 pizza mApp;
EditText et_summary;
TextView tv_total;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_total);

    mApp=((pizza) getApplicationContext());
    et_summary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_summary);
    tv_total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have chosen the" + " " +  mApp.getGlobalVarValue(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    et_summary.setText(mApp.getGlobalVarValue());
    String str = mApp.getGlobalVarValue();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"$");
    String test="";
    float total=0;
    int count=0;
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), st.nextElement().toString().substring(0,1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        test = st.nextElement().toString().substring(3,1);
        if(count>0)
            total+= Float.parseFloat(test);
        count++;
    }
    et_summary.setText(mApp.getGlobalVarValue());
    tv_total.setText("Total :" + total+"");
    mApp.setGlobalClear();


}
public boolean isFloat( String input )
{
    try
    {
        Float.parseFloat( input );
        return true;
    }
    catch( Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using SQLiteOpenHepler or Room persistence library? which are the two recommended ways to use SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the **food** table does not exist when you use `locations = loadLocationData();` within the `MenuFoodActivity`.

You could circumvent this error by creating the table before invoking the `loadLocationData` method. e.g. :-

```
db=openOrCreateDatabase("Restaurants_DB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food(id int, name text, price int);");
locations = loadLocationData();
addListenerOnButton();
initializeUI();
```

Comment: this works now there was a error created in the total activity class

Comment: If the above fixes the problem, which you say it did, you should mark the question as answered. If you have subsequent issues then you should ask another question. P.S. the error is with/due to `Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2`